# Symfony 2.3: Validate entities inside collection field

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm trying to validate entities inside a collection field with validation.yml schema but it doesn't work. I've tried it in two ways.

The first approach was with Collection constraint, but collection field throw me that some fields were missing.

The second way (I think the best way) was to try with "Valid" constraint to validate each object from collection but that doesn't work also.

In both cases I set "cascade_validation" in default form options.

So, How I can validate entities inside a collection field?

There's my validation code:

```
#
# Edition
#
Talim\ActivityBundle\Entity\Edition:
    properties:
        activity:
            - NotNull: ~
        accommodation:
            - NotNull:
        turns:
            - Valid: ~
        services:
            - Count:
                min: 1
        services:
            - Count:
                min: 1
        childRatio:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type:
                type: integer
            - GreaterThan:
                value: 1
        minAge:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type:
                type: integer
            - GreaterThan:
                value: 0
        maxAge:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type:
                type: integer
            - LessThan:
                value: 35
        specialNeeds:
            - NotNull: ~
            - Type:
                type: bool
        largeFamily:
            - NotNull: ~
            - Type:
                type: bool

#
# Turn
#
Talim\ActivityBundle\Entity\Turn:
    startAt:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type:
            type: string
        - Date: ~
    endAt:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type:
            type: string
        - Date: ~
    minPlaces:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type:
            type: string
    totalPlaces:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type:
            type: integer
        - GreaterThan:
            value: 1
```

Comment: Do you also have validation annotations somewhere in your entity files? Do you set additional validation groups?

Comment: I'll suggest you , use annotation in your entity and it will give you perfect result.Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that it's an issue from yaml? I'm using it at whole project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my code:

```
Talim\ActivityBundle\Entity\Turn:
   properties: # <--- I forgot this
      startAt:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type:
            type: string
        - Date: ~
```